# Python import on sub-folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

It`s been a while since I create my classes and import them to my script, using

```
from <folder> import <file>
```

and my file.py looks like this:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__():
```

and so on.

However, whenever I want to use this class on my main script, I have to do:

```
file.myClass()
```

Is thera a better way so I could use only "myClass()"?

Comment: `from <folder.file> import myClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated the scenario with the following directory structure:

```
.
├── outer.py
└── some_folder
    └── inner.py
```

You missed the `self` in `__init__` method:

`some_folder/inner.py`:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("myClass is initiated")
```

Import the class from the file when you want to directly use the class name.

`outer.py`:

```
from some_folder.inner import myClass

some_object = myClass()
```

Output:

```
myClass is initiated
```

Comment: @LuccaLemeMarques, yes. One observation is to use CapitalCase for class name. So, standard form of naming `myClass` is `MyClass` according to PEP8 style guide. Read more here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I'm used to camelCase, but I'll keep that in mind when it comes to Python! Thanks, regards!

Comment: just a simple question, what if I wanted to go down another folder?
could I use `from <folder1>.<folder2>.<file> import <class>` ?

Comment: @LuccaLemeMarques, yes, you can import like that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing the file, you can import the class

```
from package.module import MyClass
```